# Zookeeper cannot work correctly if one node down in cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I had problem on my cluster zookeeper, i have 2 server and each server have one zookeeper. 
ex :

```
server.1=x.x.x.x:2888:3888 
server.2=x.x.x.x:2888:3888
```

if one zookeeper down, the other one zookeeper can't run.
I don't have any idea to solve this problem, or should the best number zookeeper i have to build cluster zookeeper ?

Answer (score 2):

In a highly available Zookeeper ensemble you must configure `2n + 1` Zookeeper instances where `n` is any number greater than 1. This means that for a *Zookeeper quorum* (i.e. a healthy ensemble), you must configure an odd number of instances (3, 5, 7, ...). This is because Zookeeper cannot perform majority elections for leadership using an even number of instances.

Assuming that you have correctly configured a Zookeeper ensemble with `2n + 1` instances (quorum), there can be up to `n` failed Zookeeper instances without taking the cluster down.

If the quorum breaks, then the Zookeeper cluster will go down. This is what had happened in your case. Try to use a higher number of Zookeeper instances in your ensemble (3 or 5) and it should do the trick. Alternatively, if you don't need high availability you can still use just 1 Zookeeper instance.

Comment: can you explain to me, how kafka broker work with 5 cluster ?
thanks in advanced

Comment: @khg Do you mean 1 Kafka Broker and a Zookeeper quorum with 5 instances?

Comment: sorry, i mean more than one broker. 
example: i have 4 brokers. one leader and 3 replication. 4 broker must be connect to 5 zookeepers ?

Comment: Yes, having 4 Kafka brokers and a Zookeeper quorum with 5 instances does work. Note that for each broker, you don't specify a specific Zookeeper instance. You need to specify the addresses for all of them and Kafka broker is going to figure it out.

Comment: "where `n` is any number greater > or equal <  than 1" you would say

Answer (score 1):

ZooKeeper will work as long as **majority** of its nodes if up, if N is number of nodes in cluster it will work as long as `working_nodes_number > N/2`

Now if you have 2 nodes, and one is down (`working_nodes_number = 1`), zoo keeper won't work: `N / 2 = 1` and obviously `1 > 1` is wrong

In other words, **cluster of two servers can't stay alive even if one node is down**.

Try running 3 nodes, so that if one node goes down, there still be 2 nodes (majority) so that zookeeper will keep working

In general its a good strategy too use cluster of an odd number of nodes.
You might be interested to read [this article](https://www.corejavaguru.com/blog/bigdata/why-zookeeper-on-odd-number-nodes) that is relevant to the discussion

Comment: how about kafka broker ? if i have 5 zookeeper, should i connect to 5 nodes ?

Comment: I'm not a kafka expert, in all examples I see, kafka server is configured to connect to all the zookeper nodes (I mean the broker itself, not producer/consumer in the application). In general its a subject for different questions because kafka is a different technology and other people can help you there as well...